# Async Library ForLoop

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous

I have tried to run this code and get the say.speak commands to run one at a time using the async library. But instead the speak commands all happen at the same time. The console.logs happen in the correct order though! Does anyone know a solution?

The console solution (Time and then event name):

12:00:00 PM

Mach & Matt

4:00:00 PM

Set up help!  Microsoft Social 3.0 Chicago

4:30:00 PM

AV Check - Microsoft Social 3.0 Event Chicago

The code

```
var api = require('./api.js');
var say = require('say');
var async = require('async');
var S = require('string');
var i = 0;

api.getEvents(function (err, result) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else {
        //Intro();

        async.times(result.value.length, function (callback) {
            async.series([
                function (callback) { Time(result.value[i].start.dateTime, callback);},
                function (callback) { someAsyncTask(result.value[i].subject, callback); ++i;  },


            ])
        });

    }

});
// do two async series.. one for setup and one for read
// series 1: time convert, and send result.value[i] to series 2
// series 2: for loop to read out 
// optional callback

function Intro() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        say.speak('todays schedule is');
    }, 1000);
}

function someAsyncTask(event, callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(event);
        say.speak(event);
        // * returning err !== null will abort the execution
        // of all tasks and call finalCallback(err)
        // * result will be appended to the list of results returned to finalCallback()
        callback(/*err=*/null, /*result=*/event);
    }, 2000);
}


function Time(data, callback) {
    var cst = new Date(Date.parse(data));
    var time = cst.toLocaleTimeString();
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(time);
        say.speak(time);
    }, 2000)

    callback();
}
```

Comment: In wasn't at the same time just very fast and unnoticeable. Try increasing timeout value after each iteration and you will see difference. Hope this helps.